# Test mockery with a pipeline

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

How can I assert this:

```
$this->assertEquals('incoming', $payload['routerAction']);
```

Skipping the pipelines. I'm using phpleague/pipeline

Code:

```
class IncomingPipeline
{
    public function __invoke(array $payload)
    {
        $router = $payload['router'];
        $payload['routerAction'] = 'incoming';

        return (new Pipeline())
            ->pipe(new DispatchIncomingEventStage())
            ->pipe(BaseRouter::route($router))
            ->process($payload);
    }
}
```

I basically want to skip the Pipeline OR set andReturn($payload) on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the pipeline a dependency to `IncomingPipeline` and pass it into the constructor. That way, you could inject a pipeline without any stages in your tests.

If you want to keep it the way it is, you can use the `overload` prefix ([docs](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/mocking_hard_dependencies.html)):

```
final class IncomingPipelineTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        $pipeline = Mockery::mock('overload:' . Pipeline::class);
        $pipeline->allows('pipe')->andReturnSelf();
        $pipeline->allows('process')->andReturnArg(0);

        $payload = (new IncomingPipeline())(...);

        self::assertEquals('incoming', $payload['routerAction']);
    }
}
```